# Selector with 2 parameters

Tags: jquery

The following selector `$('.sub_menu_container',this)` has 2 parameters, the selector you want to search for and a second one. In this case its `this`. What is the use of adding that second parameter? Ive search the jquery docs but didnt find anything that could help me. Is it some kind of reference?

Comment: You might see it as well as with a parent like: $('.sub_menu_container', parent)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

the second param provides the context in which to search the element matched by the first selector

Answer (score 14):

its just like :

```
$(this).find('.sub_menu_container')
```

its a context re-format of code.

that all :)

Comment: p.s. and it is faster.

Answer (score 8):

The second parameter scopes the selector, so that it only searches inside the context of the element provided in the second parameter. It is basically the same as saying `$(this).find('.sub_menu_container');`.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the use of adding that second parameter?

As the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) explains:

> By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting
>   at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for
>   the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function.
>
> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method,
>   so $('span', this) is equivalent to $(this).find('span').

Comment: It has the same _effect_ as using `.find()`, but it saves a function call.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter is a scope for search. It means jQuery looks for first selector withing second selector.